# Get the name of the vertex in the igraph::transitivity(graph, type = "local") function in R

Tags: r, igraph, transitivity

When I use the degree(graph) function from the igraph package in R, the output comes up with the name of the vertex and its respective value, however, when I run the transitivity(graph, type = "local") function from the same package, the output is a list without names, I can't tell which node each value corresponds to.

I expected the output of the transitivity(graph, type = "local") function to be accompanied by the name of the vertices.

Comment: This is indeed an inconsistency. I recommend you open a bug report and point it out. Make sure to fill out _all_ fields of the bug report form. https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

The result is always in the same order as the `vid` parameter you specified, or if `vid` is left at its default value, then in the same order as the vertex list returned by `V(g)`.

This is true for all igraph functions, without exceptions.